# How to highlight variables in a \path?

Tags: paths, bash

Is there a way to highlight variables within a `\path`? For example in

```
\path{$HOME/some/thing.txt}
```

to highlight the `$HOME` part as Bash variable?

Or do I have to use a listing environment for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `minted`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

This is a path \mintinline{bash}{$HOME/some/thing.txt}

\usemintedstyle{emacs}

This is a path \mintinline{bash}{$HOME/some/thing.txt}

\usemintedstyle{colorful}

This is a path \mintinline{bash}{$HOME/some/thing.txt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The list of available styles can be obtained by

```
pygmentize -L styles
```

Run `pdflatex` with the `-shell-escape` option.

Answer (score 1):

A simple poor man's solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{red}{\path{$HOME}}\path{/some/thing.txt}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]